# Inject script with meteor session return converting circular structure to JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, meteor

**Expected:** when user click `#goToInputBox` in `myTemplate`, this should focus to inputbox from `anotherTemplate` without error...

I have click event:

```
Template.myTemplate.events({
  'click #goToInputBox': function () {
    Session.set('goToInputBox', $('#divOfInputBoxFromAnotherTemplate').focus());
  }
});

Session.get('goToInputBox');
```

`#divOfInputBoxFromAnotherTemplate` located at another template

When I click `#goToInputBox`, it successfully focus to input box. However console give me an error: `Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON`

What does it mean? How to get it done properly?

Comment: The `Session.set` is trying to convert a jQuery object into JSON. Since a jQuery object is a circular structure, the stringifying fails.

Comment: Have you fixed the issue?

Comment: @PraveenKumar not yet SIr.. as @Vohuman said i'm trying to use pure javascript but don't know how,, i attempted `t.find(#).focus()` and `document.getElementById(#).focus()` but not working...any idea .. ??

Comment: @KarinaL Well, the stringifying happens behind the senses. Probably the `.set` function does this. JSON is used for storing data. You can't convert a jQuery object into JSON, i.e. the line `Session.set....` is the culprit.

Comment: @KarinaL The problem as Vohuman said, lies in the array part. I tried it and kinda works for me. Posting it as an answer and we can take it from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of setting the session variable as a jQuery object or whatever, I have a better idea *and it could be possibly wrong too*:

```
Template.myTemplate.events({
  'click #goToInputBox': function () {
    Session.set('goToInputBox', document.querySelector('#divOfInputBoxFromAnotherTemplate'));
    document.querySelector('#divOfInputBoxFromAnotherTemplate').focus();
  }
});
```

I know this is repeating, but kindly try with this and let me know if it works.

Comment: yayyy,,, this work..!! thank You Sir... anyway this alone work `Session.set('goToInputBox', document.querySelector('#divOfInputBoxFromAnotherTemplate').focus());`

Comment: @KarinaL You are welcome. Please don't call me sir. Please, call me `Praveen`. `:)`

Comment: @KarinaL I am more interested in working on MeteorJS. May I know more about the project you are working, if completely fine with sharing about it? We can take it offline from StackOverflow. `:)`

Comment: @KarinaL Wow! Interesting... I guess you might like my work. Check out [Soceall](http://pkp4d.com). `:)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97759/discussion-between-praveen-kumar-and-karina-l).